# Positive Kaon decay into $\pi^+$ and $\pi^0$ suppressed

Tags: particle-physics, standard-model, mesons, pions

I am looking at the reactions of positive Kaons and am looking at 
$$K^+\to\pi^++\pi^0$$

Since the strangeness is not conserved, this has to be a Weak decay. When I try to make the Feynman diagrams for this decay, I cannot make one that is not a flavor changing neutral current.
However, PDG says the fraction of this decay is $21\%$. This does not make sense as this is a very high fraction for a suppressed decay mode. 
What am I missing?

Comment: t channel? What have you tried?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image]

Cabibbo suppressed, but not FCNC

(Apologies for poor drawing quality)